# Obtain individual results of neo4j query

Tags: neo4j

Imagine I made a query using neo4j like:

- *return me graph, where one persons name is David who has Friend Nick.*

Imagine in the database there are three different Davids who each have different friend Nick.

Hence the result returned would be like this:

[image]

You can see neo4j returned all results together, however, I want to be able to access each graph separately.

e.g. basically I want result to be **three separate** images as below (where each pair corresponds to a pair from the initial image):

[image]

However I don't know how to achieve this.

PS. I am not interested in how to do it from neo4j browser, rather from API like this: https://projects.spring.io/spring-data-neo4j/, or any other api, or purely from cypher.

Comment: The query would return records (rows) of results, which should correspond with each of the three results you are expecting (whether one of the nodes is in common with another row shouldn't matter). At that point it's up to you to process/visualize accordingly.

Comment: @InverseFalcon it would return all nodes and all links together right? How can I know from that data that a certain set of nodes and certain set of links corresponds to a *single* result of the query? Do you see what I mean? I want response to be like: `[{dataforOneResult}, {dataForSecondResult},...]` however now it returns `[{dataForAllResults}]`

Comment: I would expect separate rows with a set of results corresponding to each separate match on each row. Perhaps you should add your cypher query to your description.